# Using behaviorsubject to call method of a component

Tags: angular

I am having two unrelated components in Angular 8 and trying to call one components method from another. I am trying to use BehaviourSubject but not sure if it is property implemented. I need to call getAgreementHistory method from the agreementcomponent.I have currently tried to in the accept method. I have declared the Behavioursubject in the service.
 Could somebody tell me what the issue is

Called method component

```
export class MyAgreementsComponent implements OnInit {
  agreementsHistoryData: AgreementHistoryModel[];
  agreementsHistory: AgreementHistoryModel[];
  loading: boolean;
  myData: any;
  showAgreementReadOnly: boolean;
  public modal: any;

  constructor( public agreementsService: AgreementsService,
               public router: Router,
               private route: ActivatedRoute,
               public modalService: NgbModal) {
                this.agreementsService.agreementHistoryLoaded$.subscribe(x => x);
               }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAgreementsHistory();
  }

  public getAgreementsHistory() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.agreementsService
      .getAgreementsHistory()
      .subscribe((data: AgreementHistoryModel[]) => {
        if (data) {
          this.loading = false;
          this.agreementsHistoryData = data;
          this.getNonCompletedAgreements();
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Calling component

```
export class AgreementComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('scroll', { read: ElementRef, static: false })


  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  myData: any;
  agreementData: any;


  public scroll: ElementRef<any>;
  public loading = false;
  showAgreementReadOnly: boolean;

  constructor(public agreementsService: AgreementsService,
              public msalService: MsalService,
              public modalService: NgbModal) {


    this.isDisabled = false;
    this.todaysDate = this.GetUtcDate(new Date()).toISOString();
    this.todayDateUtc = this.todaysDate.substring(
      0,
      this.todaysDate.length - 1
    );

 }

  GetUtcDate(date: Date) {
    const now_utc = Date.UTC(
      date.getUTCFullYear(),
      date.getUTCMonth(),
      date.getUTCDate(),
      date.getUTCHours(),
      date.getUTCMinutes(),
      date.getUTCSeconds()
    );

    return new Date(now_utc);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAgreement();
  }

  public getAgreement() {
    this.loading = true;

    this.agreementsService
        .getAgreement(this.agreementsService.agreementUserId)
        .subscribe((agreementModel: AgreementModel) => {
          if (agreementModel) {
            this.myData = agreementModel;
            this.agreementData = agreementModel.data;
            this.SetWarningMessage();
            this.loading = false;
           }
        });
    }

  public CloseModal() {
        this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }

  accept() {
    this.update(Accepted);
    this.CloseModal();
    this.agreementsService.agreementHistoryLoaded$.next(true);
  }
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AgreementsService {
  private baseUrl: string;
  public data:  AgreementModel[];
  public agreementData:  AgreementModel;
  public agreementHistoryLoaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private appService: AppConfigService) {
    this.baseUrl = this.appService.getAppSettings().apiServer.agreements;
    this.agreementHistoryLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  }

public agreementUserId: number;


  public getAgreementsHistory(): Observable<AgreementHistoryModel[]> {
    this.agreementHistoryLoaded$.next(true);
    return this.http.get<AgreementHistoryModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}agreements-history`);
  }


}
```

Comment: in the AgreementComponent  you are not calling the Accept method?

Comment: Yes its been called in the AgreementComponent . Triggered from the html button click. I need to invoke getAgreementHistory method there

Comment: How are you seeing that it is not working? this.agreementsService.agreementHistoryLoaded$.subscribe(x => x); will not do alot

Comment: What do I do Alexander. What is missing ?

Comment: I created this small stackblitz based on your code and that BehaviourSubject works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3scquw

Comment: Thank Alexander for putting together a stackblitz. I can see how the true and false being set when called from respective clicks. In my case I need to trigger the getAgreementHistory method based on true value. So do  I call the service in the subscribe based on true value in the myagreements component

Comment: I changed the stackblitz

Comment: Thanks once again. I had to make a slight change. Add  this.agreementsService.agreementHistoryLoaded$.next(true); to the constructor of myagreement as there would be situation when user navigates to the myagreement page directly and hence would want to see the data

Comment: One small issue what I am facing is that i can see the method getting fired but the page not getting refreshed. Is it because i am not calling the ngOnit and directly calling the service. The whole idea of this exercise is that the page gets reloaded with the latest data

Comment: Do u need to just trigger ngOnit ?

Comment: As I understand agreementHistoryLoaded$ is just to refresh the data? Can you edit the stackblitz and indicate a bit what you want to do? I think we can refactor the whole thing if I guess correctly

Comment: There is actually a grid on myAgreements which has data. Its using the devexpress grid. Finding it bit difficult to get it set up as there are lot many dependencies involved to get it working . If it possible for you to show the page load on trigger then that would suffice.

Comment: You can ignore my previous comment as I got it to worked. It was just the timing when i was set the observable to true on click of the button which was happening too soon. As far as the concept of the communication lies, your solution solved the issue. Hence I am marking it as solved